# How to fix\update default values in a List in SharePoint 2013

Tags: c#, json, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

I am working in SharePoint 2013 where while creating a new item in a list one column should have default value is my requirement. Could any one please let me know how to update (or) fix default value for a column of a list in SP 2013.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use powershell to fix default values.

```
 $myweb= Get-SPWeb http://yoursiteURL
    $mylist = $myweb.Lists["yourlistname"]
    $myFieldName = $list.Fields["mySPFieldName"]
    $FieldName.DefaultValue = "MY Default value"
```

Comment: Hi Syed, i tried your script. unfortunately its not working.  Error message as below

Cannot index into a null array.
At C:\Users\spsetup\Code\defaultvalue.ps1:3 char:5
+     $myFieldName = $list.Fields["Default"]
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray

The property 'DefaultValue' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the
property exists and can be set.
At C:\Users\spsetup\Code\defaultvalue.ps1:4 char:5
+     $FieldName.DefaultValue = "http://google.com/"
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation

Answer (score 0):

Here is my test script(the script shared by Syed Danish Aftab just not use right variable ).

```
$myweb= Get-SPWeb http://sp:12001/
$mylist = $myweb.Lists["Chart"]
$myFieldName = $mylist.Fields["QTY"]
$myFieldName.DefaultValue = 3
$myFieldName.Update()
Write-Host 'complete'
```

Test result:

```
$myweb= Get-SPWeb http://sp:12001/
$mylist = $myweb.Lists["Chart"]
$myFieldName = $mylist.Fields["Link"]
$defaultValue=$myFieldName.DefaultValue
$myFieldName.DefaultValue = 'https://www.google.com/'
$myFieldName.Update()
Write-Host 'complete'
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Lee, thanks for response. This script used for Hyderlink column in list also? I get below error when i try script

The property 'DefaultValue' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the
property exists and can be set.
At C:\Users\spsetup\Code\defaultvalue.ps1:4 char:1
+ $myFieldName.DefaultValue = "http://google.com/"

    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\spsetup\Code\defaultvalue.ps1:5 char:1

Comment: I am try for hyderlink column. I tried your update script. I am getting below 

The property 'DefaultValue' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the
property exists and can be set.
At C:\Users\spsetup\Code\defaultvalue.ps1:5 char:1
+ $myFieldName.DefaultValue = 'https://www.google.com/'

    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\spsetup\Code\defaultvalue.ps1:6 char:1
+ $myFieldName.Update()


Please suggest me.

Comment: Try to output the field title to confirm you got the field correctly.  Write-Host $myFieldName.Title

Comment: i am getting same error in powershell -> The property 'DefaultValue' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the
property exists and can be set.
At C:\Users\spsetup\Code\defaultvalue.ps1:5 char:1
+ $myFieldName.DefaultValue = 'https://www.google.com/'
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\spsetup\Code\defaultvalue.ps1:6 char:1
+ $myFieldName.Update()

    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException